# cannot connect to TFS online

Tags: pycharm

We are switching from our local TFS server to one located on https://XXXX.visualstudio.com.  I can connect to our old server fine, however, when  I redirect to TFS online, I always get:

```
  Transport Error: 401 Error: Unauthorized
```

I am using the Alternate authentication.  Even tried running Pycharm as admin.

Everything works fine when I connect thru a browser (Visual Studio 2017 as well), Its only thru Pycharm that I have any issue.

I'm using Pycharm2018 professional addition.

Anyone else run across this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you login VSTS with correct credential?

Answer (score 1):

You need to sign in on the `Team Service` tab with your VSTS account:

[image]

Comment: SO the big issue is that there are two different plugins.  One for local TFS, and one for online.  This isn't really obviously stated.  On top of that, it really doesn't discuss out you need the TFS command line tool

I did finally get on, but I think this needs to hget documented by JetBrains a LOT.